# Is it bad practice to move template conditionals out of the template?

Tags: angular

My `.html` for a component is a little messy with conditionals.

`[attr.icon-button]="config.data.type === 'icon-button' ? '' : null"`

What if I moved it into a function or a getter?

```
get isIconButton(){
   // blah
}
```

Then

`[attr.icon-button]="isIconButton"`

Is this acceptable or discouraged?

Perhaps I feel it is verbose because there is a better method of attribute binding? A silly sample `[attr.{{config.data.type}}]` but search terms fail me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bad practice. In the [angular documentation for template expressions](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions), function calls and references to properties are considered to be the norm (See [simplicity](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#simplicity)).

You should carry in mind that your functions/getters gets executed on every change detection run. So be very careful with them. They should be quite simple and fast to execute. But since you just want to wrap a simple ternary operator, you are fine to go.